# How to color a dataframe to a conditional heatmap with same color across whole row based on a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap

So I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
Target, Achieved, Goal, Remaining
10, 5, 50, 5
4, 5, 125, 0
3, 3, 100, 0
8, 2, 25, 6
```

I want to display this dataframe with visible info based on colors, Under this criteria:

1. If goal is achieved I just wanted row to be green regardless of how surpassed goal actually is. So the whole 2nd and 3rd rows would be the same green color
2. If goal is not achieved, I want to color them based on heatmap. So here I want 4th row to be a darker shade (of lets say red) than 1st row since I am missing more on that row's goal.

For single color, following function works perfectly: Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469478/how-to-color-whole-rows-in-python-pandas-based-on-value)

```
def highlight_col(x):
    #copy df to new - original data are not changed
    df = x.copy()
    #set by condition
    mask = df['Goal Completion (%)'] >= 100
    df.loc[mask, :] = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    df.loc[~mask,:] = 'background-color: pink'
    return df
```

For a simple heatmap without excluding Goal completion condition, its possible via:

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Reds')
```

But it:

1. Includes whole dataframe
2. Color by each column separately
3. Cannot exclude rows with goals achieved
4. Could not be used inside my above function (tried using: `df.loc[~mask,:] = 'background_gradient: Reds'` in last line but didn't work either.

P.S. My Dataframe isn't very large so I prefer table coloring itself from where I can select rows instead of having a whole new viz. Any suggestions bettering the situation are highly welcomed!

### Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of dataframe?

Comment: Yupp! Just added that! Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this (using @QuangHoang methods):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',\s+')

cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('RdYlGn')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(df['Goal'].min(), 100.)

def colorRow(s):
    return [f'background-color: {mpl.colors.to_hex(cmap(norm(s["Goal"])))}' for _ in s]


df.style.apply(colorRow, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This helps. Exactly what I had in mind. Turned out setting max value was the answer. Thanks @Scott Boston

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `cmap` to a certain subset of a dataframe

```
df.style.background_gradient('Reds', subset=pd.IndexSlice[df.Goal < 100, ])
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hello! @Vishnudev This still doesnot encompass for the heatmap. The functionality you just posted is the same as what my function achieves (A lot cleaner tho. I admit)

Comment: Also not to be very specific but condition should be `>= 100`

Comment: This still does not answer my question as I want: 1. same color across each row. 2. Exclude already achieved goal rows from heatmap and color them differently

Answer (score 0):

You can try extracting the color by the value in `Goal` with `cmap`:

```
def hightlight_col(d, refcol=None, cmap='Reds'):
    min_goal, max_goal = d[refcol].agg(['min','max'])
    goals = d[refcol].sub(min_goal)/(max_goal-min_goal)
    cmap=mpl.cm.get_cmap(cmap)
    
    return pd.DataFrame([[f'background-color: {mpl.colors.to_hex(cmap(goal))}']*d.shape[1]
                   for goal in goals
                 ], index=d.index, columns=d.columns)
    
df.style.apply(hightlight_col, refcol='Goal', 
               cmap='coolwarm', axis=None)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Quang Hoang! This does not my question completely. This goes to applying heatmap to whole datafame based on single column value but it does not incorporate exclusion of already achieved goals.