# Plot heatmap from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following pandas Dataframe. `alfa_value` and `beta_value` are random, `ndcg` shall be the parameter deciding the color.

[image]

The question is: how do I do a heatmap of the pandas Dataframe?

Comment: With matplotlib or seaborn or other?. How many bins?

Comment: matplotlib or seaborn is OK :) 

Please remember that `alfa_value` and `beta_value` are random (random search), so most likely unique. The idea is to have a grid where we average the ndcg on the case we have multiple values for the some place.

Comment: Do you need to bin your `alfa_value` and `beta_value`?

Comment: I would say we need

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex] and [good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to generate a heatmap. You have to adjust the bins to group your data (analyze the mean, the std, ...)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame({'alfa_value': rng.integers(1000, 10000, 1000),
                   'beta_value': rng.random(1000),
                   'ndcg': rng.random(1000)})

out = df.pivot_table('ndcg', pd.cut(df['alfa_value'], bins=10), 
                     pd.cut(df['beta_value'], bins=10), aggfunc='mean')
sns.heatmap(out)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, Seaborn's heatmap function is a nice way to color pandas' DataFrames based on their values. Good examples and descriptions can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/making-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe)

Since you seem to want to color the row based on a different column, you are probably looking for something more like [these answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570293/how-to-color-a-dataframe-to-a-conditional-heatmap-with-same-color-across-whole-r)