# Convert pandas df to html table and apply color to pandas row based on a criteria

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, html-table

I have a dataframe like as below

```
test_id,status,revenue,cnt_days,age     
1,passed,234.54,3,21          
2,passed,543.21,5,29
11,failed,21.3,4,35
15,failed,2098.21,6,57             
51,passed,232,21,80     
75,failed,123.87,32,43

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to color the rows when `revenue is greater than 500`. So, I used `pretty_html_table` found [here](https://github.com/sbi-rviot/ph_table)

So, I tried the below using `conditions` parameter but didnt work

```
build_table(data,'blue_light', font_size='8px',font_family='Open Sans,sans-serif',
                     text_align='center',width='70px',index=False, conditions={'Revenue': {'max':500,'max_color': 'red'}},even_color='black',even_bg_color='white')
```

But this didn't apply any color to the columns.

How can I use this to apply color, so I can use this `html table` in my email body?

I expect my output to be like as below with column header in yellow color and revenue > 500 rows in red color

[image]

Comment: It is the same case that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469478/how-to-color-whole-rows-in-python-pandas-based-on-value

Comment: @jpg997 - but do you know whether it will retain format when we convert to html table? Thats why didnt use style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `.style.apply` and `.set_table_styles`

```py
def highlight(row):
    if row['revenue'] > 500:
        return ['background-color: red'] * len(row)
    else:
        return [''] * len(row)

s = df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)
s = s.set_table_styles([
    {
        'selector': '.col_heading',
        'props': 'background-color: yellow; color: black;'
    }
])

s.to_html('output.html')
```

[image]

Comment: @TheGreat Updated the answer. `output.html` contains the table in picture.

Comment: can you try using build_table method that I have used from pretty html table package? I dont think it will work. I tried already

Comment: @TheGreat Have never used that package.

Comment: when I do `s.to_html`, I get an error like ` TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: @TheGreat Couldn't reproduce the error, can you try replace `row['revenue']` with `float(row['revenue'])`?

Comment: let's say my revenue has values in terms of percentage like 234% (with pct symbol), do you know how can we compare? I guess thats why it is throwing error

Comment: @TheGreat That's the reason, you should convert `revenue` column to float type first.

Comment: I solved it but one minor issue. why is that your table doesn't have full border? meaning, your border lines are white. How can we make it black?

Comment: @TheGreat Maybe you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812819/pandas-dataframe-style-lost-table-border