# pandas dataframe to html - border not accurate

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, styleframe

I have a dataframe like as below

```
test_id,status,total,cnt_days,age     
1,passed,234%,3,21          
2,passed,54%,5,29
11,failed,21%,4,35
15,failed,20%.21,6,57             
51,passed,23%,21,80     
75,failed,12%,32,43

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

My objective is to

a) Have dark border lines between rows and column using `black color`

b) Use `Green` color for header

c) Use `Red` color for rows where Total > 30%

d) convert the styled dataframe to a html object

e) Export the styled dataframe to a .xlsx excel file

So, with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301986/convert-pandas-df-to-html-table-and-apply-color-to-pandas-row-based-on-a-criteri), I tried the below

```
def highlight(row):
    if row['total'] > 30:
        return ['background-color: red'] * len(row)
    else:
        return [''] * len(row)

s = data.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)
    #data['Total'] = data['Total'].astype(str) + "%"
    s = s.set_properties(
    **{'border': '1px black solid !important'}).set_table_styles([{
        'selector': '.col_heading',
        'props': 'background-color: green; color: black;'
    }])
    output = s.to_html(index=False)
```

But this produces incorrect output with gaps between different cells and borders. Another problem is my `Total` column has `%` symbol in it. How can I use that to do > 30% check and finally also display the `% symbol` in output table.

So, I expect my output to be like as below. you can see how there are no gap in borders between each cell and rows. I want the output to be like an excel table.

[image]

Comment: I replied in the Github issue regarding the styling of the xlsx file: https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame/issues/121. Styling HTML has never been in the scope of `styleframe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = s.set_properties(
    **{'border': '1px black solid !important'}).set_table_attributes(
    'style="border-collapse:collapse"').set_table_styles([{
        'selector': '.col_heading',
        'props': 'background-color: green; color: black; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px black solid !important;'
    }])
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: great. how did you find out that `border-collapse` will give us borders between cells and rows? because I tried with borders forever but couldn't get the layout

Comment: how can we reduce the font size though?

Comment: I tried this `'font-size': '9pt'` but it changes only column values. How can change the size of dataframe columns/headers?

Comment: About the 'border-collapse' property, I found it on w3schools. I manage to set the fonts to the headers and table by adding them right after the 'border-collapse' property in both places('set_table_attributes' and 'set_table_styles'). If you want to style other elements, the default CSS classes (for the different selectors) can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html